# in a proxy, formatting a browser request before sending it out to the host

Tags: c, proxy, network-programming

For class, I'm writing a basic proxy server in c.

In the professor's example (which is java), he takes the browser's request, which looks like this:

```
GET http://www.cs.rpi.edu/index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.cs.rpi.edu
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: __utma=138860844.163543584.1329315062.1329315062.1329315062.1;__utmz=138860844.1329315062.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

And formats it to look like this, plus the Accept and User-Agent headers, before sending it out to the host server:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.cs.rpi.edu
```

I've done this also, but now I run into 2 problems, and 1 question:

A. The message sends to the server okay, because connect() and write() don't give me any error, but when I go to read() the server response (perhaps wrongfully expecting HTML?), the program freezes and just sits forever until I ctrl+C. I cannot for the life of me find a cause:

```
  /* write a message out on the socket connection */
  int n = write( sock, clientrequest, strlen( clientrequest ) );

  if ( n < strlen( clientrequest ) )
  {
    perror( "write() failed" );
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  printf("Made it here.\n\n");

  char buffer2[1024];
  n = read( sock, buffer2, 1024 );
  if ( n < 1 )
  {
    perror( "read() failed" );
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  else
  {
    buffer2[n] = '\0';
    printf( "Rcvd message from server: \n\n----\n\n%s\n\n----\n\n", buffer2 );
  }

  printf("But not here.\n\n");
```

B. Say I'm connecting to something like www.google.com. There is no /index.html, so what should go after the GET in the formatted request?

C. Why does the request need to be formatted in this fashion, rather than just sent out as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Are you certain that there are 2 newlines at the end of your modified clientrequest string? If not, then the server is still waiting for you to send the rest of the request.

Also, you don't want to declare failure if the first write() call didn't send all of the data. You should sit in a loop and keep writing until you drain your buffer. if there was an actual error, -1 will be returned, and then you can declare an emergency.

B) Just ask for '/', as in "GET / HTTP/1.1". The server will know what to do.

C) Formatted in this fashion, as in, the request with only the GET and Host: lines? Sometimes, the function of a proxy server is privacy: The browser divulges a lot of information about itself. This proxy example is stripping a lot of those lines.

Comment: before I've even finished reading, there are NOT 2 newlines. I'm going to go change that now. thank you SO much. I knew that, too; I just totally forgot.